# Bokeh graph shifting to the right

Tags: graph, bokeh

I have a Django app using bokeh without the bokeh-server.
In my HTML I have this:

```
   <body>
    <div class="container">
       <div id="title">
           <h3 style="color: yellow;">{{ title|safe }}</h3>
        </div>
           <div class="graph">
             {{ div1|safe }}
            {{ graph|safe }}
       </div>
    <div id="menu">
           {{ link|safe }}
       </div>
       <div class="table">

           {{ table|safe }}
       </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

In my css I have this:

```
    .graph{
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-left: -15px;
    }
```

This is the size of my scatterplot graph with the tools:

```
  plot = figure(tools=TOOLS, x_axis_label='Position', y_axis_label='-    height',plot_width=1000,plot_height=500,y_range=(-3.2,max_value+3))
```

On top of the page I'm using bootstrap to login in my webpage. But I can't get my bokeh graph to fit in the container.It keeps on shifting to the right.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question by myself:
in the style tag of css in html for the container or the body, do not put any:

```
  text-align:center;
```